Is it possible to add new report ranges as a Salesforce Admin for users to select?

I want to add a few new date ranges that can be selected when making a report. Is this possible as a Salesforce Admin?

No, the ranges are predetermined, the users would need to choose custom and pick their time frame.
The ranges that come out of the box are just dynamic choices anyway. If you select this month, it will update itself next month when next month becomes this month.
If you want something customized static range do custom.

I see, thanks for the quick response.
